# Integer value in TextView

Tags: android, textview

How can I display an Integer value in TextView?

When I try, I get an error `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID`

Comment: Six answers, and noone mentions why it doesn't "just work" when you specify an integer value in the setText() method. After a bit looking around I've concluded that the problem is that setText() with an integer value assumes that the integer is actually a resource ID number.

Comment: and thats why the app crashes with a weird error `UncaughtException: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("" + 4);
```

Comment: @BoldijarPaul, `setText(String.valueOf(variable));` sample code provided in [Muhammad Abdullah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3994387/6398434) doesn't and I can confirm it works pretty well.

Comment: @JorgeAmVF both work good, but the 1st one will give you a lint warning.

Answer (score 86):

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(String.valueOf(number));
```

or

```
tv.setText(""+number);
```

Comment: Nice, no warning with the first one

Answer (score 16):

**If you want it to display on your layout you should**

For example:

**activity_layout.XML file**

```xml
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/example_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**On the activity.java file**

```java
    final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.example_tv);
    textView.setText(Integer.toString(yourNumberHere));
```

*In the first line on the XML file you can see:*

```xml
android:id="@+id/example_tv"
```

That's where you get the **id** to change in the .java file for the `findViewById(R.id.example_tv)`

Hope I made myself clear, I just went with this explanation because a lot of times people seem to know the ".setText()" method, they just can't change the text in the "UI".

---

**EDIT**
*Since this is a fairly old answer, and [Kotlin is the preferred language](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/google-io-2019-empowering-developers-to-build-experiences-on-Android-Play.html) for Android development, here's its counterpart.*

With the same XML layout:

You can either use the `findViewbyId()` or use [Kotlin synthetic properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#importing-synthetic-properties):

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.example_tv).text = yourNumberHere.toString()

// Or

example_tv?.text = yourNumberHere.toString()
```

The [`toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/to-string.html#tostring) is from Kotlin's [`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/index.html) object (comparable to the Java `Object`):

> The root of the Kotlin class hierarchy. **Every** Kotlin class has **Any** as
>   a superclass.

Comment: Java + Android never gets old

Answer (score 15):

Consider using String#format with proper format specifications (%d or %f) instead.

```
int value = 10;

textView.setText(String.format("%d",value));
```

This will handle fraction separator and locale specific digits properly

Comment: This is the correct answer to support multiple language integer

Answer (score 7):

Alternative approach:

```
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
 tv.setText(Integer.toString(integer));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = Integer.toString(10);
```

Then `setText(s)`

Comment: This is just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4080552).

Answer (score 1):

just found an advance and most currently used method to set string in textView

textView.setText(String.valueOf(YourIntegerNumber));

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3994387).

Comment: my bad did not saw it

Answer (score 0):

It might be cleaner for some people to work with an Integer object so you can just call toString() directly on the object:

```
Integer length = my_text_view.getText().getLength();
counter_text_view.setText( length.toString() );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tv.setText(Integer.toString(intValue))
```

Comment: ʍѳђઽ૯ท What was the issue with this answer, you wrote the same answer. It's the difference in writing or its is a way to reduce points