# Printing integer values in a textview and thread sleep time

Tags: android

How do I print integer values in a textview and also when I increasing the sleep time in the thread its not working correctly in android.

```
package com.example.chaljayar;   
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
import android.os.Bundle;   
import android.app.Activity;   
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable 

   {

       TextView Tv;
       int num = 0, i = 0;
       String con = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text);
    Thread test = new Thread(this);
    test.start();
}
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(i <= 100)
        {
            try{            
                    con += Integer.toString(i);
                    Tv.setText(con);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: What exactly is not working? What does it do and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: What seems to be the error you receive after running this?

Comment: trying to print i values in textview but it is not printing.....

Comment: and if i increase the sleep time also not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this To Thread alone and the other out of (try/catch) :

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you want any thing about print int values in textview show this link please :

[Integer value in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994315/integer-value-in-textview)

Comment: i am trying this but the error is showing "unfortunately the application is stopped"

Comment: Are you want create timer ?

Comment: if i give sleep(10) its working correct and if i increase the sleep time it working not properly..

Comment: If you want to create timer show this link please :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how

show the correct answer and try it in the Eclipse ,,, The Answer it's do what do you want :)

about this code I think it's have problem because when the program will be call more and more threads in the while and crashed

Comment: you can't use the sleep in while that's stupid way to make timer !!

Comment: yap i know is a stupid way i don't want to make timer Acctulay i am griping on thread in android but sleep creats problem for me...

Comment: when use thread.sleep you can use it in if statement and in any where in your program but not in the loop !! you are call the sleep more than once ,,, sure that's could be crashed your app !!

how you can sleep your app if it slept :\