# TextView.setText(int resid)

Tags: java, android

Lets say I want a textview to display 5.

I assume I can use TextView.setText(5).

But in the above case, the compiler would be looking for a resource id 5 and not the integer 5.

What should I do if I really want to display the "integer" ?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer value in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994315/integer-value-in-textview)

Answer (score 5):

```
TextView.setText(Integer.toString(5))
```

convert to string

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast it to String (now compiler won't it interpret as resource):

```
TextView.setText(5 + "").
TextView.setText(String.valueOf(5));
TextView.setText(Integer.toString(5));
```

Comment: useless string concatenation ... String.valueOf(5) would be better ... no offense!

Comment: @gunar you right i already added another possible approaches.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView.setText(new Integer(5).toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you actually have 5 (five) choices, but the first 2 are the most common.

[image: setText]

1) `txtTextView.setText(String.valueOf(5)) // or Integers's equivalent`

2) `textTextView.setText(R.string.value_of_5) // this would be an int value declared in strings.xml`