# Retrieving numbers in Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have been able to retrieve strings and files in Parse. However, I have difficulty retrieving number from the number column. In particular, I want to retrieve number from Parse and cast it into a `TextView` that will display the number.

Below is the code I have to retrieve a string:

```
@Override
public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {
    for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
        // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gende r
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);

        mUserAgeRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistage);
        mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Age").toString()); 
    }//for loop
}
```

In particular, I would like the following line to be converted into a number instead of a string

```
mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Age").toString());
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: Why don't you use `Integer.parseInt()`?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Were would I change to include 
                        Integer.parseInt() mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Age").toString());

Comment: Refer to [How to convert string to int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java), but be careful when you call [`setText()` with `int`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994315/integer-value-in-textview).

Comment: thanks Andrew, how does int iage = Integer.parseInt("UserAge");
                        mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(iage);  look?