# How to randomly assign 1 to 10 number on button when execute onCreate Method ? #Android

Tags: android

Could any one help me how to randomly assign 1 to 8 number on button when  execute `onCreate` method ?  I have a problem I am creating jigsaw type little game on numbers and I want to assign randomly 1 to 8 numbers on button when app execute `onCreate` Method.

```
public void gernate(){
    int min = 1; int max=8;
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand =  r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min ;

    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button btn7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button btn9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);

    btn1.setText(rand);
    btn2.setText(rand);


}
```

MY BAD LOGIC IS ABOVE CAN SOME ONE CORRECT I GET ALL BUTTON AND THEN SET 
RNDOMLY NUMBERS BY RANDOM FUNCTION BUT WHEN I RUN MY APP .. EMULATOR NOT EXECUTE MY APP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer value in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994315/integer-value-in-textview)

Comment: @Andre Not possibly, but definitely!

Answer (score 1):

1) For a random integer between 1 and 8 use:

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt(7) + 1 //gets a random number between 0-7, then adds 1
```

2) You have to change your `rand` result to a String before setting the text because `setText` takes a String -

```
String rand_as_string = Integer.toString(rand);
```

or you can do it this way as well:

```
String stringRand = "" + randNum;
```

This is the full code, tested and works:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Random generator = new Random();
        int randNum = generator.nextInt(7) + 1;

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        String stringRand = Integer.toString(randNum); // OR use: String stringRand = "" + randNum;
        btn.setText(stringRand);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't downvote, this is the correct answer, all he has to do is convert the random integer to a string before setting the text on the button

Comment: i have 8 button and i want to assign randomly 1 to 8  numbers on all eight button  your code assign same number on all button i am worried

Comment: No no, call Random r = new Random(); only once! Every time you want to generate a random number after that just use r.nextInt

Comment: Also a somewhat easier way to convert an Int to a String is just to append it to an empty string, e.g. "String stringRand = "" + randNum;"